# R NMI with different labels

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have 20 elements with labels. I'd like to clustering this elements through some techniques without using the labels, for example Hierarchical clustering.
Now for each of my elements I have the original labels, for example:

```
 c(rep("a",7),rep("b","8"),rep("c",5)) ## my labels
```

and the labels obtained through the hierarchical clustering

```
 c(1,1,1,1,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,3,3,1,2,3,3,3) ## labels through HC
```

Now, How i Can use normalised mutual information with different labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly, this shouldn't be a problem. Just remember that NMI takes data frames or matrices as input.

If you would take your variable names as 1...20, this should work:

```
NMI(cbind(seq(1:20), original.labels), cbind(seq(1:20), new.labels))
```

Answer (score 0):

NMI compares every label in one with *every* label in the other.

So it does not matter if they are different.

It only matters how they intersect.